# ABP IO Code sample for run multiple databases for multi-tenancy

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

**Please notice that I am talking about ABP.io, not the Boilerplate framework.**

The in-build free module Tenant-Management is developed to work with multiple tenants and a unique database. however, the documentation says that the framework has a built-in friendly way to use the multiple database approach, including:

- new dbContext
- database migration and seeding
- Connection String service

I am new in ABP IO, and I want a sample that employs the framework elements to implement a single database for every tenant.

I get started by overriding the tenant create sync method of the tenant management module as follows.

```
 [Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
[ExposeServices(typeof(ITenantAppService), typeof(TenantAppService), typeof(ExtendedTenantManagementAppService))]
public class ExtendedTenantManagementAppService : TenantAppService
{

    public ExtendedTenantManagementAppService(ITenantRepository tenantRepository,
        ITenantManager tenantManager,
        IDataSeeder dataSeeder) : base(tenantRepository, tenantManager, dataSeeder)
    {
        LocalizationResource = typeof(WorkspacesManagerResource);
        ObjectMapperContext = typeof(WorkspacesManagerApplicationModule);
    }


    public override async Task<TenantDto> CreateAsync(TenantCreateDto input)
    {
        var tenant = await TenantManager.CreateAsync(input.Name);

        input.MapExtraPropertiesTo(tenant);

        await TenantRepository.InsertAsync(tenant);

        await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

        using (CurrentTenant.Change(tenant.Id, tenant.Name))
        {
            //TODO: Handle database creation?
            // create database
            // migrate 
            // seed with essential data


            await DataSeeder.SeedAsync(
                            new DataSeedContext(tenant.Id)
                                .WithProperty("AdminEmail", input.AdminEmailAddress)
                                .WithProperty("AdminPassword", input.AdminPassword)
                            );
        }

        return ObjectMapper.Map<Tenant, TenantDto>(tenant);
    }
}
```

Any code sample?

Comment: to implement a single database for every tenant in `abp.io` you should only specify the connection string when creating a new tenant, the same dbcontext will be used but with a different connection

Comment: Yes, I have released everything related to tenancy management as an in-built module. the mistake was in the connection string name. Thanks for your pass